# Easiest way of defining and using of Global Variable

Tags: variables, f#, global

```
"first part" &&&& fun _ ->
 let ident
"second part" &&&& fun _ ->
 ident ....
```

I need to use variable "ident".

I just need to pass value of variable from first part of test to second one...

I want to ask you if there is any easy way how to define and use global variable or even if you have better (and easy) idea of doing that

Keep in mind, please, that I am a beginner, so I would prefer easier ones.

Comment: `let ident = ...` at the start of the file? all `lets` are global by default.

Comment: ah ok i am just suprised that he is telling that ident is not defined in second part

Comment: So i wrote the comment before your edit.  In this case you will need to do something like `let mutable g = (* some default value *) ... "first part ... g <- value`

Comment: i am doing something wrong but in the meantime ` let ident = Var.Global("X", typeof<R>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this was getting out of hand for comments this is how I would do it for an example

```
let mutable t = 0

let first =
    t <- 1 + 1
    //other stuff

let second = 
    //can use t here and it will have a value of 2
```

In some cases you have to use a ref:

```
let t = ref 0

let first =
    t := 1 + 1
    //other stuff

let second = 
    //can use t here and it will have a value of 2 - 
    // you use "!t" to get the value
```

Comment: thx so much guys to you all :) its working now.. need to progress in my poor skills in F#

Answer (score 5):

Global variables will often make your code **difficult to work with** - particularly if they are mutable.

Instead, **consider returning the values you need to keep track of as composite values**. An easy data type to start with would be a tuple:

```
let ``first part`` id =
    let someOtherValue = "Foo"
    someOtherValue, id + 1
```

This function takes an `int` (the current ID) as input, and returns `string * int` (a tuple where the first element is a `string`, and the second element and `int`) as output.

You can call it like this:

```
> let other, newId = ``first part`` 42;;

val other : string = "Foo"
val newId : int = 43
```

Notice that you can use pattern matching to immediately destructure the values into two named symbols: `other` and `newId`.

Your second function could also take an ID as input:

```
let ``second part`` id otherArgument =
    // use id here, if you need it
    "Bar"
```

You can call it like this, with the `newId` value from above:

```
> let result = ``second part`` newId "Baz";;

val result : string = "Bar"
```

---

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can define a record for the purpose:

```
type Identifiable<'a> = { Id : int; Value : 'a }
```

Now you can begin to define higher-order functions to deal with such a type, such as e.g. a `map` function:

```
module Identifiable =
    let map f x = { Id = x.Id; Value = f x.Value }

    // Other functions go here...
```

This is a function that maps the `Value` of an Identifiable from one value to another, but preserves the identity.

Here's a simple example of using it:

```
> let original = { Id = 42; Value = "1337" };;

val original : Identifiable<string> = {Id = 42;
                                       Value = "1337";}

> let result' = original |> Identifiable.map System.Int32.Parse;;

val result' : Identifiable<int> = {Id = 42;
                                   Value = 1337;}
```

As you can see, it preserves the value `42`, but changes the `Value` from a `string` to an `int`.

You can still change the ID explicitly, if you want to do that:

```
> let result'' = { result' with Id = 7 };;

val result'' : Identifiable<int> = {Id = 7;
                                    Value = 1337;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define `ident` at the top of your file like this :

```
let ident = "foo" 

// rest of your code using ident
```

`ident` are global and you can use in the next part of your file.

**EDIT :**

If `ident` wil change in the next part of your code, use this :

```
let ident = ref "foo"
```

Comment: i tried both ways but in yours its telling me that variable is no mutable and in John its telling me "The mutable var 'ident' is used in invalid way. Mutable vars cannot be captured by closures....."

Comment: @Allegon in that case, use a ref - I will update my answer

Comment: thx so much guys to you all :) its working now.. need to progress in my poor skills in F#